# How to completely "lock" a folder to prevent new file creations (copy & paste included)

Tags: windows, delphi, directory, locking

I am currently opening a folder to restrict access to it, as I don't want to set an ACL on the actual folder.

Is this possible with `CreateFile()`?

Copy and Pasting works, and that is a problem for me. Drag-and-drop from Windows Explorer does not, however, and has the desired effect.

Any advice here?

I'm merely trying to prevent as much access as possible to the folder with `CreateFile()` for security reasons, and would prefer to use the `CreateFile()` API.

Comment: So, you choose to ignore an API that is *specifically designed* for security, to use a general-purpose API that has little to do with security? Nice choice there. What you have described is a typical [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/), where `CreateFile()` is `Y` here. What `X` exactly are you really trying to accomplish, that you think `CreateFile()` is the solution for?

Comment: And WHY don't you want to use ACL!? That's just the thing you exactly (!) need here!

Comment: When you say folder do you think about a standard folder on disk drive that can be used by any application that has access to it or are you interested in some special folder that will be accessed only by your application. If it is the latter they you might be interesting in creating and registering a virtual file structure with your application similar as it is done when you connect a smart phone to your computer and then get different folder structure based on what transport mode do you chose on the smartphone.